# Setar valor para combo com Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Uso o script abaixo para alimentar alguns campos de texto com valores do banco Oracle. Mas surgiu uma situação em que preciso alimentar um combo de dois valores (ATIVO e INATIVO). No Ajax abaixo, ele retorna os valores do banco mas não seta no index.php. Se eu tiro o campo 'situação' ele alimenta os outros 2 (nome e codigo). Mas se deixo ele ativo, ele para no 'Pesquisando...". Como faço para setar os valores do banco no combobox? Obrigado

INDEX.php

```html
              <tr>
                 <td>Código (4 digitos): </td>
                 <td><input type = "text" name="codigo" id="codigo" size = 15 maxlength = 4 onkeyup="troca_campo2(this)" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event)"></td>
              </tr>


              <tr>
                 <td>Nome Completo: </td>
                 <td><input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" size=70 maxlength=50 onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"></td>
               </tr>

              <tr>
                  <td>Situação:</td>
                  <td><select name="situacao">
                       <option id="situacaoA" value="ATIVO">ATIVO</option>
                       <option id="situacaoI" value="INATIVO">INATIVO</option>
                       </select></td>
              </tr>
```

ajax.JS

```js
/**
  * Função para criar um objeto XMLHTTPRequest
  */
 function CriaRequest() {
     try{
         request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (IEAtual){

         try{
             request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(IEAntigo){

             try{
                 request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(falha){
                 request = false;
             }
         }
     }

     if (!request)
         alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
     else
         return request;
}

//Não executa nada até a execução terminar
var requestActive = false;

function getDados() {
    if (requestActive) return;
    requestActive = true;
    // Declaração de Variáveis
    /* Caso for necessário passar mais parametros além do nome
     * basta adicionar uma variável aqui e editar no GET
     */
    var ids = ["codigo", "nome", "situacao"];
    var cracha = document.getElementById("cracha").value; //CAMPO QUE VEM DO INDEX.PHP
    var result = document.getElementById("content"); //DIV DE RETORNO DOS DADOS
    var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

    // Exibe a mensagem de progresso
    //result.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Progresso.gif"/>';
    ids.forEach(function (id) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = 'Pesquisando...';
    });

    // Iniciar uma requisição
    // Se for colocar mais variáveis, é aqui. Exemplo: processa.php?txtnome=" + nome + '&admissao=' + admissao
    xmlreq.open("GET", "processa.php?cracha=" + cracha, true);

    // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de estado
    xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
        if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
            // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
            if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
                //Se o retorno foi vazio do Oracle
                if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {
                    document.getElementById("cracha").focus();
                    document.getElementById("cracha").value = '';
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = 'NÃO ENCONTRADO!';
                    });
                //Se encontrou dados
                } else {
                    //Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
                    var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);
                    // função para preencher os campos com os dados
                    ids.forEach(function (id) {
                        document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
                    });
                }
            } else {
                result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
            }
        }
        requestActive = false;
    };
    xmlreq.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do que é retornado do servidor para o ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso a melhor forma não é passar `id` para `<option>` e sim para o `<select>`, e no código que você seta os valores, você passa o id do select com o valor.

Seu html:

```
<select name="situacao" id="situacao">
  <option value="ATIVO">ATIVO</option>
  <option value="INATIVO">INATIVO</option>
</select>
```

Chamado do js:

```
document.getElementById("situacao").value = "ATIVO";
```

Comment: Como assim? Pode me mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: De fato a tag [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) pode ter `id` sim. Talvez o OP tenha outro uso para esses ids.

Comment: Me expressei mal, editei a resposta.

Comment: Deu certo, agora setou os valores. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente deve haver um erro no seu console, pois suspeito que no momento em que tenta acessar `document.getElementById(id)` onde o `id` é igual a `situacao`, não é encontrado, pois sua combo não tem `id`, apenas `name`. Então ele tenta atribui valor à propriedade `value` de `null`.

De qualquer forma, você deveria fazer um tratamento diferente para a combo dentro do loop:

```
ids.forEach(function (id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    if (el != null) {
        if (el.type && el.type == "text") {
            el.value = 'NÃO ENCONTRADO!';
        }
        else if (el.tagName == "select") {
            el.disabled = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Ou algo assim, fiz de cabeça, tem que ser melhorado.

Comment: Realmente, coloquei o ID e ele não travou. Mas ainda não sei como tratar o combo...

Comment: @Diego no caso de *"não encontrado"* você pode desabilitar a combo e habilitar quando *encontrado* .

Comment: @Diego fiz um update.. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s5bm3hf3/1/).

Comment: DontVoteMeDown deu certo agora, testei a tua ideia e a do @henriquedpereira e funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Diego tranquilo, qualquer coisa estamos aí.